# Why do I not have GlassFish option on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, server

I am trying to get GlassFish server working on my Eclipse Luna (with WTP installed).

However, I do not have a **GlassFish Server** option in the **Download Additional Server Adapters** there:

[image]

Also, when I try to download a Mojarra library for my JSF project, I don't have an option to install GlassFish either:

[image]

**How should I install GlassFish server and tools on my Eclipse Luna?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install [this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-luna#.VItrzCvF_GA) plugin. Brought up by a simple google search of glassfish plugin eclipse luna

Comment: Will this plugin automatically add a glassfish server to my Servers list? or should I also do something else? I tried installing this before, but it didn't add a glassfish server and didn't add an ability to easily create .xhtml JSF pages

Comment: is there anything else I should do after installing this?

Comment: @Victor2748 it adds it. Ifact I use it in my workspace.

Comment: @Victor2748 I installed this plugin and glassfish was automatically added to the list of servers. this adds it to the list of available servers but does not create the server.

Comment: @Victor2748 when you install it you then have to create a new glassfish server in the server vire

Comment: I've installed the same plugin but still not sign of `glassfish` server in the list to add. is there any workaround I can try?

Comment: Same here as @MohammadFaisal. Tried Luna SR1 and SR2 on OSX and Linux Mint. Installed Glassfish tools via market place and update site http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.3.4/luna/repository/. It makes no difference. The "new server" dialog does not show a glassfish option.

Comment: @ralf I am not sure have no experience with linux based systems

Comment: Figured it out. The plugin insists on Java 8 as the Eclipse runtime. But now I am stuck with the "glassfish start hangs at 69%" problem on OSX Yosemite. It works on Mint 17 though.

Comment: @Ralf: you are right. the plugin works on `Java 7` or above and I'm also facing the *69%* issue on windows.

Comment: @ralf i also have no experience with OSX though am glad to hear that linux was resolved. I suppose you should open a new question fior the mac issue

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem and found below steps as the solution by installing pulgin..hope this will help:
install Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE) from eclipse market place which includes Glassfish support for eclipse.

And remember that when you are installing J2EE SDK you will get the Glassfish in it. you don't need it separately.

And eclipse required plugins to be installed for glasssfish.

Instructions for installing Plugins:

Open Help menu > select Eclipse Market Place.

Write OEPE in search box > select Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse from the List and Press Install button.

After installing this plugins when you choose from server, GlassFish server option will automatically be in the list  if you have installed J2ee jdk.

Answer (score -1):

Change your jdk version to jdk8.. it worked for me when I upgraded to 8.

Comment: I doubt that changing the JDK version will make a difference, because I was using GlassFish for java EE 7 at that time.

Comment: I was in jdk7 when faced same issue.... I downloaded from eclipse market place and it doesn't show up in server adapter list... As a last resort i tried with 8 and worked..

Comment: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools.  ....  this link mentions the jdk requirement with respect to eclipse version..

Comment: IMPORTANT: Please consult the following table regarding the minimum version of Java required to run GlassFish Tools.

      Mars - Java 8
      Luna - Java 8
      Kepler - Java 7
     Juno - Java 6
  So I still feel you should have java8 as you are using Eclipse -Luna